# Why does a range that starts at a negative number not iterate?

Tags: for-loop, iterator, rust

I have just started to learn `Rust`. During my first steps with this language, I found a strange behaviour, when an iteration is performed inside `main` or in another function as in following example:

```
fn myfunc(x: &Vec<f64>) {
    let n = x.len();
    println!("    n: {:?}", n);
    for i in -1 .. n {
        println!("    i: {}", i);
    }
}

fn main() {
    for j in -1 .. 6 {
        println!("j: {}", j);
    }

    let field = vec![1.; 6];
    myfunc(&field);
}
```

While the loop in `main` is correctly displayed, nothing is printed for the loop inside `myfunc` and I get following output:

```
j: -1
j: 0
j: 1
j: 2
j: 3
j: 4
j: 5
    n: 6
```

What is the cause of this behaviour?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Type inference is causing both of the numbers in your range to be `usize`, which cannot represent negative numbers. Thus, the range is from [`usize::MAX`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/usize/constant.MAX.html) to `n`, which never has any members.

To find this out, I used a trick to print out the types of things:

```
let () = -1 .. x.len();
```

Which has this error:

```
error: mismatched types:
 expected `core::ops::Range<usize>`,
    found `()`
(expected struct `core::ops::Range`,
    found ()) [E0308]
let () = -1 .. x.len();
    ^~
```

Diving into the details, [`slice::len`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/primitive.slice.html#method.len) returns a `usize`. Your `-1` is an untyped integral value, which will conform to fit whatever context it needs (if there's nothing for it to conform to, it will fall back to an `i32`).

In this case, it's as if you actually typed `(-1 as usize)..x.len()`.

The good news is that you probably don't want to start at `-1` anyway. Slices are zero-indexed:

```
fn myfunc(x: &[f64]) {
    let n = x.len();
    println!("    n: {:?}", n);
    for i in 0..n {
        println!("    i: {}", i);
    }
}
```

**Extra good news** is that this annoyance was [fixed in the newest versions of Rust](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/27026). It will cause a warning and then eventually an error:

```
warning: unary negation of unsigned integers will be feature gated in the future
     for i in -1 .. n {
              ^~
```

Also note that you should never accept a `&Vec<T>` as a parameter. Always use a `&[T]` as it's more flexible and you lose nothing.

Comment: That's surprising behavior. I wish `rustc` would at least emit a warning that the a negative value is "wrapped" around.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Oh, thanks for reminding me! It actually *is* fixed, see my update. ^_^